# Десериализация класса, перенесенного в другой пакет

Tags: android, serialize, java, serializable, unserialize

Был раньше класс `Class1` с таким пакетом: `com.application.package1`  
Его перенесли в такой пакет: `com.application.package2`  
можно ли десериализовать в класс с новым пакетом объекты, сериализованные со старым пакетом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, т.к. с точки зрения JVM это разные классы.

Если вам нужно обеспечить совместимость двух компонент (продюсера и потребителя), то придется преобразовывать оба компонента в несколько шагов таким образом, чтобы в итоге они работали с одним и тем же новым классом.